# clickable town names google maps

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps

I was wondering if it is possible to have clickable town names in google maps api. I want to be able click eg. Pretoria -> then it must alert me with the Town name, Province name and country name.

kind regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could achieve this by using a combination of events and reverse geocoding.

There is an example of exactly this here. Click anywhere on the map to reverse geocode the location.

http://gmaps-samples-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/geocoder/v3-geocoder-tool.html#q%3D54.572062%2C31.640625

Comment: Thanks for that, very good starting point for me. You do not know of anything where the town names are drawn as links on the map ?

Comment: The only, way to do something like that would be via a custom Kml layer - possibly using fusion tables http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/layers.html

Comment: Hoped there would be a simple solution. I think i should the change the way i want to use the maps in my app then. Thanks for the help :-)